# SQL Server 2008 Combine two rows into one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have written pretty straightforward queries so far, so I am now looking a help to write a SQL statement so that it will combine two separate period end rows from a table into one row. The rows are basically can be matched by their PId, Region, Market, Code, Source. For example-

if 1st row is:

```
Id   Region Market  CODE    Source  Period_End  Amt     Pct
100 CAN     CABLE   V1      SA      20120930    100.00  0.2
```

and 2nd row is:

```
Id  Region  Market  CODE    Source  Period_End  Amt     Pct 
100 CAN     CABLE   V1      SA      20121231    200.00  0.5
```

Then the SQL should return this result:

```
Id  Region  Market  CODE    Source  Period_End_1    Amt_1   Pct_1   Period_End_2    Amt_2   Pct_2

100 CAN     CABLE   V1      SA      20120930        100.00  0.2     20121231        200.00  0.5
```

Your help is really appreciated.

Ana.

---

Thanks for your responses. This is what I started with but I am not sure if I am on right direction or not. I also noticed as I would add more and more information to the row based on Period End then the below query would be too long with redundant "case condition" in each select.

```
select 
    A.id , A.region, A.market, A.code, A.source ,  
    case when period_end = @day_id1 then period_end else '' end as Period_End_1,
    case when period_end = @day_id2 then period_end else '' end as Period_End_2, 
    case when period_end = @day_id1 then Amt else 0.0 end as Amt_1,
    case when period_end = @day_id2 then Amt else 0.0 end as Amt_2, 
    case when period_end = @day_id1 then Pct else 0.0 end as Pct_1,
    case when period_end = @day_id2 then pct else 0.0 end as Pct_2, 
from 
    products A with (nolock)
where 
    A.product_id in (select product_id from #products) -- temp table holding multiple Ids
```

Comment: You've said you're looking for help to do this, but you haven't given us anything to help you with unless we just write your queries for you. Do you have some existing code or error messages to share that we can help fix?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.Id  
      ,t1.Region  
      ,t1.Market  
      ,t1.CODE    
      ,t1.Source
      ,t1.Period_End  AS Period_End_1 
      ,t1.Amt         AS Amt_1
      ,t1.Pct         AS Pct_1
      ,t2.Period_End  AS Period_End_2 
      ,t2.Amt         AS Amt_2
      ,t2.Pct         AS Pct_2
FROM Table_Name t1 
INNER JOIN TABLE_Name t2  ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.ID = 100 AND t1.Period_End <> t2.Period_End
```

Comment: Join should be on `Id, Region, Market, Code, Source` and `t1.PeriodEnd <> t2.PeriodEnd` if you're joining on just `id` the row will always join itself too

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're trying to `pivot` multiple rows into multiple columns.

Assuming it's always 2 rows you're trying to combine, using the `period_end` field to order the first from the second, then something like this should work using `max` with `case` to `pivot` your results:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *, 
           Row_Number() Over (Partition By Id, Region, Market, Code, Source 
                              Order By Period_End) rn
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT Id, 
    Region, 
    Market, 
    Code,   
    Source,
    max(case when rn = 1 then Period_End end) Period_End_1,
    max(case when rn = 1 then Amt end) Amt_1,
    max(case when rn = 1 then Pct end) Pct_1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then Period_End end) Period_End_2,
    max(case when rn = 2 then Amt end) Amt_2,
    max(case when rn = 2 then Pct end) Pct_2
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Id, Region, Market, Code, Source
```

If you have more potential `period_end` dates, then you might need to use dynamic sql to achieve your results.

Comment: I would always have one of the two dates so I am pretty sure I wouln't need dynamic sql.